# Including fonts using javascript prevents other javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading fonts with this piece of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var path = '//easy.myfonts.net/v2/js?sid=84112(font-family=John+Sans+Text)&sid=84097(font-family=John+Sans+Lite)&key=Ff0uyBryqy',
                  protocol = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:'),
                  trial = document.createElement('script');
        trial.type = 'text/javascript';
        trial.src = protocol + path;
        trial.async = true;
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        head.appendChild(trial);
     })();
</script>
```

It loads the fonts but then my form javascript doesnt work.

```
Nette.addEvent(window, 'load', function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
                Nette.initForm(document.forms[i]);
        }
});
```

But when I put alert after head.appendChild it works just fine.

I tried to set async to false or remove it completely but the result is still the same.

There is a head snippet without fonts

```
<script></script>
<script src="/nette/www/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<link media="screen, projection" href="/nette/www/css/settings-live-form-validation.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this is a head snippet including fonts:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://easy.myfonts.net/v2/get?U4EE9fOUltFonWL1AupSkAm2&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cCo6Ly8qL3YyL2dldD9VNEVFOWZPVWx0Rm9uV0wxQXVwU2tBbTIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE0MzQ0NDU0NjB9fX1dfQ__&Signature=PM~gjifl7dOhJzXBzdSjLJhBZgxxBF9YmiNjwaS1xqJInBexm4qW2Fx1Vo-0p0S5gYxgGiFTIVzR57DDJCwHNYY39dY9mv8YlluqypJSXGU0dgP8WrIwg1N2SuN8ZcFhmmfVzdK2y9iOhUHs8~R93fXAZ~WNzTYnPcaVxOWs3SWLkCJfZjGSyptYs~94~d8d1LhJFKrvboswFdAIaLsFbw73Xd624rEHqGFhhwcQ-nx4J4zD2GgOyB4RpGukiaALP-SDY775uRVphvX8L0rp4Pp5PQEiuSMW3tMhjhG~qTuqhoAoe8sSQqEVau2eNgPeWtAeDSLdUbl4rKEwlNO4cg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJN6QFZEE4BZCL6XQ"></script>
    <script></script>
    <script src="/nette/www/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <link media="screen, projection" href="/nette/www/css/settings-live-form-validation.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script> //fonts includer
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://easy.myfonts.net/v2/js?sid=84112(font-family=John+Sans+Text)&sid=84097(font-family=John+Sans+Lite)&key=Ff0uyBryqy"></script>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.myfonts.net/widgets/webfont_preview_bar/webfont_preview_bar.css">
```

Comment: Can't you use `<link />` to add the fonts?

Comment: Also check in console for any errors you have!

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors in your browser console?

Comment: <link href='link to your font' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

Comment: It is from external source and I got this script. It adds several <script> and <links> to <head>. But I will try load it only with link.

Comment: And I get no errors in console.

Comment: Wait your code still doesn't work when you remove this font scripts entirely or did I misread that? Your code looks fine. What does your DOM look like in the end? Has something gone wrong in your `head` tag, like removed scripts?

Comment: When I remove this script it works fine. Those fonts break it.  And I have to use it with the <script> because it is from https://www.myfonts.com where you get this script includer.

Comment: @tttpapi Yes, I get that, but since you haven't posted, say, a snippet of your code, I can't see whether it messes up your `head` tag. A faulty implementation of this would break your DOM, otherwise it should make no difference or throw an error.

Comment: @somethinghere I added head snippets with and without including fonts.

Comment: @tttpapi Ah yes, sorry. Also, you can use `document.head` to get the head tag, then you don't need `getElementByTagName`, which older browsers don;t even understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80560/discussion-between-tttpapi-and-somethinghere).

Comment: @somethinghere ... I'm pretty sure you have that backwards. `getElementsByTagName()` was supported back in IE6. `document.head` didn't show up until IE9

Answer (score 3):

You need to **close** your script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://easy.myfonts.net/v2/get?U4EE9fOUltFonWL1AupSkAm2&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cCo6Ly8qL3YyL2dldD9VNEVFOWZPVWx0Rm9uV0wxQXVwU2tBbTIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE0MzQ0NDU0NjB9fX1dfQ__&Signature=PM~gjifl7dOhJzXBzdSjLJhBZgxxBF9YmiNjwaS1xqJInBexm4qW2Fx1Vo-0p0S5gYxgGiFTIVzR57DDJCwHNYY39dY9mv8YlluqypJSXGU0dgP8WrIwg1N2SuN8ZcFhmmfVzdK2y9iOhUHs8~R93fXAZ~WNzTYnPcaVxOWs3SWLkCJfZjGSyptYs~94~d8d1LhJFKrvboswFdAIaLsFbw73Xd624rEHqGFhhwcQ-nx4J4zD2GgOyB4RpGukiaALP-SDY775uRVphvX8L0rp4Pp5PQEiuSMW3tMhjhG~qTuqhoAoe8sSQqEVau2eNgPeWtAeDSLdUbl4rKEwlNO4cg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJN6QFZEE4BZCL6XQ"></script>
<script src="/nette/www/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<link media="screen, projection" href="/nette/www/css/settings-live-form-validation.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://easy.myfonts.net/v2/js?sid=84112(font-family=John+Sans+Text)&sid=84097(font-family=John+Sans+Lite)&key=Ff0uyBryqy"></script>
```

You have a whole bunch of issues related to defining scripts with `<script>` but then not closing them with `</script>`.

Comment: Just wondering, he was using `document.createElement("script")`, would that not autmatically take care of this...? He's not writing a string here... So whats going on here?

Comment: @somethinghere ... Yes, for that part of the OP's code...However, there are still issues *before* that (in the HTML code that has been added prior to the JS font script definition).

Comment: Sry, those tags are of course closed. Just when I copied them from firebug it didnt copy the closing tags.

Comment: @tttpapi That's what I suspected... `createElement` always creates an opened and closed element in any other case, so this wouldn't be the issue..